# Seclecting photos from picker and posting on to server issue

Tags: iphone, image, post, memory-management, uiimagepickercontroller

I am facing an issue related to application's memory consumption getting increased drastically. I need to select photos using uiimage picker controller, post those multiple images on to the server and dismiss the controller. But each time I chose the photos, the memory of the application increases and doesn't reduce and at some point the application crashes. I have already checked for memory leaks but didn't find any.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any answers to this question would just be guesses unless you can post some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

We have noticed that each time the UIImagePickerController is presented, the application internally consumes some memory which it doesn't relinquish even when the picker controller is dismissed.In our application, we have need to invoke the picker controller frequently and so after sometime the overall memory of the application increases and the application's crashes. We created a sample application and found that this leak in the picker is existing. After searching various forums , we tried the below snippet code in the picker delegate method but it was in vain:

picker.delegate = nil;
[picker release];
picker = nil;

We also tried to create a static picker controller, but still the issue persisted.

Could anyone provide some inputs on it.